# Ion-item-option does not expand to full width after swiping beyond threshold (bounces back)

Tags: ionic4

**Question**
Is there some way to have expandable item-option to go full width after expanding beyond the threshold (after threshold is when ionSwipe event is fired)

**Problem demo**
Expandable bounces back to the left after drag end when it’s expected to go off-screen to the right and replaced by the red delete button.

[Problem Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DAp1.gif) Expandable bounces back to the left after drag end when it’s expected to go off-screen to the right and replaced by the red delete button.

[Desired behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eO6jh.gif) Trash is expandable here. Dragging the item left after a certain point, it will continue going left and get replaced by the red trash button which its height animates down to disappear.

**Code**

```html
<ion-item-sliding @slideInOut *ngFor="let bagItem of bag.bagItemsList">

    <!-- SLIDING OPTION FOR DELETE -->
    <ion-item-options side="start" (ionSwipe)="bag.remove(bagItem)"> 
      <ion-item-option color="danger" (click)="bag.remove(bagItem)" expandable="true">DELETE</ion-item-option>
    </ion-item-options>

    <ion-item>
        <!-- CONTENT -->
    </ion-item>

</ion-item-sliding>
```

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out?

Comment: Unfortunately not :( I settled with making it slide/compress and disappear.